# how to properly annotate object to fix Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm getting the following error: Object is possibly 'null' on this.auth.currentUser how do I properly annotate this line to make the error go away?

Method:

```
doPasswordUpdate = (password: string): Promise<void> =>
    this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password)
```

Annotation: 
`auth: firebase.auth.Auth`

Any help is appreciatedQ!

Comment: Just google the error, there's a bunch of posts answering this, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried a few solutions but most of them don't work like:
 doPasswordUpdate = (password: string): Promise<void> | void => {
    if (this.auth) {
      this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password)
    }
  }

or      this.auth!.currentUser.updatePassword(password)

it still throws the same error

Comment: Well you'll have to check each step right, like `if (this.auth && this.auth.currentUser && this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword) { ... }`, or something similar, since any one of those could null. Might not need to check `this`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I see what I did wrong now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you are probably better off doing something like:

```
doPasswordUpdate = (password: string): Promise<void> =>
  this.auth.currentUser  
    ? this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password)
    : Promise.resolve()
```