# error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I'm unable to deploy a firebase function as a result of the following error:

[image]

Here's the code...really simple

```js
        for (let i = 0; i < users.data().subscribers.length; i++) {
            const addToken = (userId === users.data().subscribers[i]);
            const notify = await db.collection('users').doc(`${users.data().subscribers[i]}`).get();
            if (notify.data().sendNotify) {isNotifyTrue = notify.data().sendNotify; }

            console.log('isNotifyTrue', notify.data().sendNotify);
            if ((!addToken) && (!isNotifyTrue)) {
                const devicesRef = db.collection('devices').where('userId', '==', users.data().subscribers[i]);
                const device = await devicesRef.get();
                devices.push(device);
                console.log('device', device);
                console.log('devices', devices);
            }
        }
```

I've tried:
            if (notify.data().sendNotify) {isNotifyTrue = notify.data().sendNotify; }

and

```
        if (notify) {isNotifyTrue = notify.data().sendNotify; }
```

and I've tried:

```
        isNotifyTrue = notify.data().sendNotify ? notify.data().sendNotify : true;
```

also tried:

```js
            if ((notify.data().sendNotify !== 'undefined') || (notify.data() !== null) || notify.data() !== undefined) {
                sendNotify =  notify.data().sendNotify; }
```

as a result of[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

Comment: I tried that one too to no avail:

src/index.ts:56:44 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

56             if (notify && notify.data() && notify.data().sendNotify) {

Comment: https://shinesolutions.com/2017/01/06/writing-safer-code-with-typescript-strict-null-checks-type-guards/

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do.  It's a warning that notify.data().sendNotify could possibly be undefined.  But I'm checking if it's undefined and it still gives me the error.

Comment: I'm not sure the compiler is smart enough to make that distinction.  If you're sure that it's never going to be undefined, I'd just ignore the warning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there's not way to ignore the warning when attempting to deploy the firebase function to firebase cloud functions that I know of.  But I'm sure it won't be null.  How do you ignore the warning

Comment: By not paying any attention to it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey firebase cloud function won't let you upload with those errors