# object is possibly undefined angular unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I was working on unit testing I am getting below error

> Object is possibly 'undefined'

```
 it('should set the dataSource filter to the provided argument', () => {
  component.applyFilter('filterValue');
   expect(this.dataSource.filter).toEqual('filterValue');
  })

it('should set the dataSource filter to the provided argument', () => {
   component.applyFilter('filterValue');
   expect(this.DMDataSource.filter).toEqual('filterValue');
 })
```

I am getting error inside expect(this) what is the mistake here.

Please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

Comment: Mr M : Did my answer helped ?

Comment: I gave tick mark i have one more question which i asked can you please help on that

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058914/angular-ngif-not-working-as-expected-angular-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `component.dataSource` rather than `this.dataSource` inside `expect` block

You need to evaluate the `dataSource` defined inside `component` instance

```
it('should set the dataSource filter to the provided argument', () => {
  component.applyFilter('filterValue');
   expect(component.dataSource.filter).toEqual('filterValue');
  })

it('should set the dataSource filter to the provided argument', () => {
   component.applyFilter('filterValue');
   expect(component.DMDataSource.filter).toEqual('filterValue');
 })
```