# Angular 8 "ngIf" condition not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have 3 divs based on my condition. Those divs have to appear, actually it is working as expected for the first time

1. div a
2. div b
3. div c

This is the condition I gave

```
<div class="pl-2 flex-grow-1 d-flex" *ngIf="getInfo!==3 && getInfo !== 5"></div>

<div class="pl-2 flex-grow-1 d-flex" *ngIf="getInfo==3"></div>

<div class="pl-2 flex-grow-1 d-flex" *ngIf="getInfo==5"></div>
```

Initially when I load first page **first div** is working as expected, no issue there. But when I got to second page the **second div loaded** and when again I come to first page, the second div is loading and not the first div.

Here is my TS code

```
   const getinfo = this.caService.info.subscribe((response) => {
      this.getInfo = +response 
   });
```

Comment: Its obvious because your condition does not satisfy

Comment: @Sajeetharan Can you please help on this

Comment: Actually I gave !== right in that case if it is not 3 or 5 this that div shouldn’t come right

Comment: @Mr.M When does the getInfo value change ? or add some codes related to that ?

Comment: When I click the next page the get infovalue is changing I gave the code in ngoninit

Comment: Can you show your typescript code that goes along with this?

Comment: Your condition is fine, it's proboly somthing else, see this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-ckt4ar?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Asaf I changed as per your code but still not working

Comment: If you do !== that will check value and type stricter inequality. if both satisfied then it return true. I suggest you to use != that will check value.

Comment: replace getinfo for getBasicInfo in your HTML

Comment: @Shabbir I tried this also not worked

Comment: @pedro I changed the method still not working

Comment: I'm wondering what the service does that you're subscribing to. Is it always giving you the same observable or is the observable being re-created everytime? Also, it is not clear how often you subscribe to that observable... It could be that the first time you subscribe the subscription remains active and everytime you subscribe you get more active subscriptions that interfere with eachother (they all overwrite the same property).