# Error TS2532 - Object is possibly 'undefined' where it cannot be undefined

Tags: typescript, strict

I am doing the following object access. But TS complains that it may be undefined even when I check for it.

```
      if (metrics[key0]) {
        if (metrics[key0][key1]) {

          […]metrics[key0][key1]]);
        }
      }
```

=> Error TS2532 in line 2 and 4.
Playground example: [Click Me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAkFMCdNBnA9gWzqgLtAlgY3qAQ1gXUVgBMAoLAO3RgDMCc4BZSTXfAb0tH9AAjAK4MGMADKQAbpAA2AfgBcoboWHksiFTWHJBMADShpWcpG2hd%20mKAC%20Abj4DBWTAXoARRAHcacxAJyZVV1TUtrA2hjU3MIvSj7JwFQOQ9IGhwATxDeFJSCDS0VNWRaHQSjQmkAcwqbaNBkAgAPesS7Q2d8kzMLEqbyq0rGglr2qua24Yb7bqTKO0pKOQ4mjmw8FXZOPFAAXlVHSgxN%20AA6ETFJGXkD0MLwpQBmGL7tAFYF065Lt2h0t4-AEgvc1I9iq9enElF9jiAQMtKCBQABJGiEGiIdAAC1sOBQAAdEDQMug0alEIhCaBcdBEMIajjCKksPByYgGAh5JAcPRyOtdqBqegtDQLhScHicABrUBYLm4uDwHl8yACyAtNnkgg0AXCFW0vFYaAmAhyYSQc6UAni8kyyBZAAM9wA5FdxNApLI5K7CPgHVlObSsoSLFyfngHD0Y7HYyj3aJPd75H62QgCOIzXIzDaSezQIGAIxu2IWP0EAOO4PoUPhwVnADatbDwcDToAutG4z3%20CjzgPlgrQAAKSPwRvtjsASlU82HY42XEnjs7K6yRZnc9jq3J0nNlvu4-Xa%20LXfmSyWCOAQA)

When I change it to `metrics[key0]?.[key1]` the error is gone. But why do I need that? In the if it cannot be null or undefined?

Edit: Please do not again mark this as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined). In that topic there is no check for null or undefined.

Comment: Your playground contains a lot of infos. You should add some of it in the question to complete it.
However, the actual type of key1 is never (it doesn't answer the question, but it shouldn't be never, should it?)

Comment: This is a known behavior which happens when you are checking a variable property of an object, like `metrics[key0]`.  If you save `metrics[key0]` to a variable and check that variable then you won't have the error.

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista you are right there is a small error. Type of key1 is not correct.