# Reading props in a AWS CDK app in Typescript

Tags: javascript, go, aws-cdk

I am a newbie to go language and I am passing some properties `props?` to my CDK appstack with the following signature: `props?: cdk.StackProps`

Now, when I just print the variable `props` on the console by typing `console.log(props)` I see this (as expected):

```
{ env: { account: '112358132134', region: 'us-west-2' } }
```

However, when I do something like this: `console.log(props['env'])` I get the following error:

```
console.log(props["env"]["account"])
```

I get this error:

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

The goal for me is to use this property for my business logic. How can I read it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The access to `account` property may fail as the `env` property is `optional`.

Your TypeScript settings seem to have `strict null checking` turned on, thus code won't compile due to the potential `TypeError`.

You can turn off the `strict null checking`, although generally it's better to keep it enabled.

You can also rewrite your code to cope with possibility of `env` being `undefined`

```js
console.log(props.env?.account); // If You have high enough TS version
// OR
console.log(props['env'] ? props['env']['account'] : undefined);
```