# How to solve Object is possibly 'undefined' in TypeScript error when pass theme to a function?

Tags: typescript, react-native-elements

I want to build a component that allows me to have different button sizes with `react-native-elements`. To achieve this I build a custom component which have a property `size` and with this I access dynamically to a specific size of the button with its respective styles inside `theme` object. Everything works as expected, but I have the following error in typescript: `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.` every time I try to access to the `sizes` object inside `theme` with the bracket notation.

### Custom button component

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Button, FullTheme, ThemeContext } from 'react-native-elements';

export type Props = Button['props'];
export type Theme = Partial<FullTheme>;

const styles = {
  button: (theme: Partial<FullTheme>, size: string) => ({
    padding: theme?.Button?.sizes[size]?.padding, // problem here
  }),
  title: (theme: Partial<FullTheme>, size: string) => ({
    fontSize: theme?.Button?.sizes[size]?.fontSize, // problem here
    lineHeight: theme?.Button?.sizes[size]?.lineHeight, // problem here
    fontFamily: theme?.Button?.font?.fontFamily,
  }),
};

function ButtonElement(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const {
    size = 'medium',
    children,
    ...rest
  } = props;
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <Button
      titleStyle={styles.title(theme, size)}
      buttonStyle={styles.button(theme, size)}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

#### theme.ts

```js
export const theme = {
  Button: {
    font: {
      fontFamily: 'inter-display-bold',
    },
    sizes: {
      small: {
        fontSize: 14,
        padding: 10,
        lineHeight: 20,
      },
      medium: {
        fontSize: 18,
        padding: 14,
        lineHeight: 24,
      },
      large: {
        fontSize: 20,
        padding: 18,
        lineHeight: 24,
      },
    },
  },
}

// react-native-elements.d.ts -> Extending the default theme to manage button sizes 
import 'react-native-elements';
import { StyleProp, TextStyle } from 'react-native';

export type Sizes = {[index: string]: TextStyle};
export type Size = 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';

declare module 'react-native-elements' {
  export interface ButtonProps {
    font?: TextStyle;
    sizes?: Sizes;
    size?: Size;
  }

  export interface FullTheme {
    Button: Partial<ButtonProps>;
  }
}
```

### pass `theme` object to the components tree

```js
// pass theme to the component tree
import { theme } from '@common/styles/theme';

export default function App(): JSX.Element | null {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Navigation />
        <StatusBar />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

### what I have tried

- I've used the `?` operator as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58401023/8582246) answer.
- I also used some suggestions mentioned in this [post](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-solve-typescript-possibly-undefined-value), using `if` statement to verify `theme` is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'` every time I try to access to the sizes object inside theme with the bracket notation.

That's interesting, because the only place you don't use [the optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is after the `sizes` field.

You have two options:

1. If you know that the `sizes` field will always never be null, undefined, or not there, then you can use TypeScript's [non-null assertion type-operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (a compile-time type-system-only thing).
2. Try doing `theme?.Button?.sizes?[size]?.fontSize` (a run-time thing).