# cannot solve ts error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```js
  const queryInput = useRef()
  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (queryInput && queryInput.current) {
      console.log(`queryInput.current.value`, queryInput?.current?.value ?? null)
    }
  }
  return (
...
```

And I'm getting the following error in vscode:

```
(property) MutableRefObject<undefined>.current: undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

Even though I tried to avoid it with the if clause and the optional chaining operator.

From the console I get the same error:

```sh
$ npx tsc
pages/_app.tsx:14:47 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

14       console.log(`queryInput.current.value`, queryInput?.current?.value ?? null)
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Also checked this SO answer: [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

and this blog post: https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-solve-typescript-possibly-undefined-value

but I can't seem to solve the issue

BTW, this is my ts version:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.2"
```

Comment: Try to pass `null` to your `useRef` hook - `useRef(null);` and see if that helps anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was fixed by passing initial value of `null` to the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook:

```js
const queryInput = useRef(null);
```

Comment: This comment does not solve the error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'