# Angular route and object possibly undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to import this example in my Application:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-breadcrumb-router

But in the file `breadcrumb.component.ts` the Visual Studio Code says

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

for this line:

```
const label = route.routeConfig ? route.routeConfig.data['breadcrumb'] : 'Home';
```

So I can't use it and I don't understand why.

Comment: 2 question...did you set up your routes correctly from the example, and if so, have you tried console logging what's in route.routeConfig.data?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Optional Chaining ?. operator:

```
const label = route?.routeConfig?.data['breadcrumb'] ?? 'Home';
```

Take a look at [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58401023/10743709)

I guess you use a newer version of Typescript or somehow activated that rule.