# Object is possibly 'undefined'. after upgrading from typescript 3.7.2 to 3.8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using typescript on a react project and I just upgraded from Typescript 3.7.2 to 3.8. Now I'm getting an `Object is possibly 'undefined'.` everywhere in the code base where I am doing something line this:

`let fieldType = currentFilter ? currentFilter.fieldType : "TEXT";`

Here is what the error looks like in VS code
[image]

Any suggestions on why this isn't working now?

Comment: You can just add an exclamation to the end to tell typescript that currentFilter is not null or undefined i.e. `currentFilter!.fieldType`

Comment: Seems like a bug in your IDE?  I checked a few different versions and all seems to work [in the TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/ND5Dxm).  When you have an error that shouldn't be happening, I have to make the obvious suggestion: turn everything off an on again.

Comment: Use if else statement You will be able to achieve it.Because Ternary operator does not correctly narrow types (while equivalent if statement does). Check this similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined