# Fix the Object is possibly 'undefined' error message

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I fix the *Object is possibly 'undefined'* error message that appears when a property is defined as conditional within a interface.

I've tried the following:

- Using IF conditions
- Using the OR logical operator
- Using the keyword as

```js
export interface ICourseContent {
  id: number;
  uid?: string;
  text: ICourseContentElementText;
  image?: ICourseContentElementImage;
}


export interface ICourseContentElementImage {
  name: string;
  uid?: string;
  url: string;
  alt?: string;
  caption?: string;
}

static resetCourseContentUids(courseContents: ICourseContent[], courseContentIndex: number): ICourseContent[] {
  if (courseContents[courseContentIndex].image) {
    // Error appears here - TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    courseContents[courseContentIndex].image.uid = `${CourseContentElementType.IMAGE}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(10)}`;
  }
  courseContents[courseContentIndex].button.forEach((courseContentButton) => {
    courseContentButton.uid = `${CourseContentElementType.BUTTON}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(10)}`;
  });
  return courseContents;
}
```

Comment: what is the courseContents length & the value of courseContentIndex ?

Comment: courseContentIndex is an integer, courseContents.length should be > 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined

Comment: Yes. But what is the length of the courseContents in your case?  One of the reason you get undefined is, the data for that index is unavailable.

Comment: This is being called from a service as a static utility method, so I'm not really sure how to answer your question.

Comment: Put a console.log of courseContents & coutseContentIndex and add the response in the question.