# TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to an API calls and I generate class for API response model but I can't get reponse values.
Here is y codes.

I Made app component.ts like that ons_list is my response object but I can't get ons_list.success

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { getOnsService } from "../../service/getOns.service";
import { result } from "../../model/result";
import { gold } from "../../model/gold.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  providers: [],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ons_list?: gold;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.get_Ons()
  }

  constructor(private service: getOnsService) {
    service.getOns().subscribe((response: gold) => {
      this.ons_list = response;
    });
    console.log(this.ons_list);
  }
  get_Ons() {
    this.service.getOns().subscribe((response: gold) => {
      this.ons_list = response;
    });
    console.log(this.ons_list);
  }
}
```

getOns.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { result } from "../model/result";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { gold } from "../model/gold.model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class getOnsService {
  getheaders() {
    return new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': 'apikey 71kRhLc4nPehMJ6iPerw4s:4qStHMIhye28Ih4HjrqqFg'
    });
  }
  header = this.getheaders();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  root_url = "https://api.collectapi.com/economy/";
  getOns(): Observable<gold> {
    return this.http.get<gold>(this.root_url + "goldPrice", { headers: this.header });
  }
}
```

gold.model.ts

```
import { result } from "./result";

export class gold {
  success?: string;
  result?: result[];
}
```

result.model.ts

```
export class result {
  name?: string;
  buy?: number;
  sell?: string;
}
```

home.component.html

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-3 ">
    <p-card header="ONS">

      <ul>
        <li>
          {{ons_list.success}}
        </li>
      </ul>

    </p-card>
  </div>
```

This is my error

[image]

This is API service

[image]

Comment: The compiler is right, `ons_list` may be `undefined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular:: error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615939/angular-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

Comment: I allready define it in home.component.ts line 11. is it wrong?

Comment: ı fixed the problem. ı change ons_list : any; but ı dont know is it a good way to fix?

Comment: You define it in the callback function of an API call, but this is an asynchronous operation. What about the time while the request is performed? What if the request fails? In those two scenarios, it remains `undefined` and may lead to errors if not properly handled. No, using `any` is a very bad idea. You need to properly handled the possibility of it being `undefined`. For more details, please see the linked question.

Comment: @IsmailYanık line 11 is a declaration which means there is no value assigned and hence it is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Declare Problem

The error message means that the success parameter can be of undefined type, but you haven't handled what should happen in that case. There are several possible solutions to the problem.

```
export class gold {
  success?: string; // is not required: string | undefined
  result?: result[];
}
```

#### Solution # 1

- success is required

```
export class gold {
  success: string; // required parameter (it can only be of string)
  result?: result[];
}
```

#### Solution # 2

- check that the success parameter was declared

```html
<div v-if="ons_list.success">
  {{ ons_list.success }}
</div>
```

#### Solution # 3

- If it's undefined, then let it be a default text

```html
{{ ons_list.success ?? 'is undefined' }} <!-- it can only be of string -->
```

or

```html
{{ String(ons_list.success) }} <!-- it can only be of string -->
```

#### Solution # 4

- disable TypeScript undefined check: [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)
- tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

#### More information

- [What is `strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) - TS Docs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ı trid all ways except solution 3 you had write but they did'nt work. solution #1 : if ı delete " ? " character ı get error : (TS2564: Property 'success' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor).
solution #2 : ı dont know why but ı get syntax error.

Comment: I have updated my response. I wrote the answers in the order I recommend their use. If the "success" parameter is not mandatory, then use the current 2. solution, and you will not receive an exception error.

Comment: In the case of the 3. solution, you might get an error because the object itself is not yet an object, so it may be advisable to use `ons_list?.success`.

Comment: thankyou for everything but ı cant fix it. yeah meybe if ı try sol. 4 it could be fixed but its not looks the true way. i find a way : I define emty gold object in constructer. constructure(){
ons_list= new gold();
}
then ı can get ons_list.name  but ı cant ons_list.buy my error isUNRESOLVED VARİABLE whatis this