# Ts2532, Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to patch a task in a project that I'm creating with the mean stack. All the api's work, but when I try to patch an element, with the id param, there's an error which says:

```
"Object is possibly 'undefined'".
```

What I want to do is:

1. Get the element with a precise id
2. Use that id as query to patch that element

This is the code:

```js
    export class TaskServicesService {
        
      constructor(private myHttp: HttpClient) { }
    
      async updateTask(payload: any) : Promise<any> {
        const task = await this.myHttp.get('http://localhost:3000/').toPromise();
        const elId: any = task.id;
        return await this.myHttp.patch('http://localhost:3000/list/', {title: payload}).toPromise();
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Try using optional chaining operator - `?`:

```js
const task: any = await this.myHttp.get('http://localhost:3000/').toPromise();
const elId: any = task?.id;
```

If you are sure that `task` has value other than **null** or **undefined**, you can also use non-null assertion operator - `!`:

```js
const task: any = await this.myHttp.get('http://localhost:3000/').toPromise();
const elId: any = task!.id;
```

Comment: Or `const elId = task!.id` if one is sure that `id` is set.

Comment: You are right, it can also be used. Let me add that to the answer.

Comment: This, in part worked, but it still says: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: Yeah, I didn't add `any` as a type. I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the right value (rvalue) of the equation is probably `undefined`. One way to avoid this error is to check if an object is `undefined` before using it as a right value. I understand that in your application this error is caused by the `task.id` object. Hopefully we can fix this problem by:

```js
if(task.id !== null && task.id !== undefined)
{
    const elId: task.id;
    return await this.myHttp.patch('http://localhost:3000/list/', {title: payload}).toPromise();
}
else
{
    /* Error Handling */
}
```