# error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' on sort

Tags: angular, typescript

Could anybody holp me?
I have following situation:

I'm initalize variable like this:
`let tableData: ShootingRange[] = [];`

The I fill tableData:

```
  this.shootingRngeService.GetShootingRanges()
   .subscribe({
     next: ((value: any) => {
       tableData = value;
       this.dataSource.data = tableData;
     }),
     error: ((value: any) => {      
     })
     }
   )
```

then I wish to sort it like this:

```
  CustomSort(field: string){

    const myproperty = 'Name' as const;

    if(tableData != undefined){

    let sorted = tableData.sort((a,b) => {
      if (b[myproperty] < a[myproperty] ) return 1;
      if (b[myproperty] > a[myproperty] ) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
      for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
        console.log(tableData[i])
      }
    }
  }
```

But I have following error:
Error: app/components/shootingRange/shooting-range-list/shooting-range-list.component.ts:119:27 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

119       if (b[myproperty] > a[myproperty] ) return -1;

Anybody have an idea what is wrong? If I use hard coded sample array this sorting works fine....

Comment: It means what it says, `b[myproperty]` or `a[myproperty]` may be undefined. You can't use `undefined` as one side of a `>` or `<` comparison. So check if one or both of them is undefined before comparing, or substitute a suitable default value (e.g. `if ((b[myproperty] ?? 0) < (a[myproperty] ?? 0)) return 1;`) or, assert that there will always be a value (`if (b[myproperty]! < a[myproperty]!) return 1;`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to answer without seeing the `ShootingRange` interface.

I'm guessing it's either that the `Name` field of that interface is optional. So TypeScript can't guarantee that the value is set.