# Object Is possibly 'undefined' in this function

Tags: typescript, postgresql, deno

I'm writing a function for a router in Deno which queries data from my database. But I get this error :

> error: TS2532 [ERROR]: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
> getUser.rowDescription.columns.map((columnItem:any,i:any)=>{

I'm using https://deno.land/x/postgres@v0.14.3/mod.ts
for postgres, in case my query syntax is wrong.

code:

```ts
const logInUser = async(inputEmail:any,inputPassword:any)=>{
    try{
        await client.connect();
        const getUser  =await client.queryArray`SELECT email,password FROM usersinfosreel WHERE email = ${inputEmail}`;
        
        
        const arrangeData = new Array();
        getUser.rows.map(p=>{
            
            let column:any = new Object();
            getUser.rowDescription.columns.map((columnItem:any,i:any)=>{
                column[columnItem.name] = p[i]
            })
            arrangeData.push(column);
        })
        if(arrangeData.length > 1){
            return false;
        }
        const checkedPassword = await bcrypt.compare(inputPassword,arrangeData[0].password);
        if (checkedPassword == false){
            return false;
        }
        await client.end();
        return true;
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve the error 'TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884488/how-can-i-solve-the-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined)

Comment: no even if adding question marks should solve this issue i don't know where to put them, and i tried like that : getUser.rowDescription?.columns?.map() but same result