# how to solve error Object is possibly 'undefined' angular 14 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

in the previous version of angular the bellow code normally working for me, but now in angular 14 it gives me the error `Object is possibly undefined`

```
 this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
```

the error is `event.total` section here is my complete code in typescript

```
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
  progress: number;
  message: string;
  @Output() public onUploadFinished = new EventEmitter();
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  uploadFile = (files) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    
    this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/upload', formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
      .subscribe({
        next: (event) => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.message = 'Upload success.';
          this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
        }
      },
      error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => console.log(err)
    });
  }
}
```

can anyone help me with how to solve this error????
thanks

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58401023/7651583, use it like `event?.total`

Comment: in my case on the code above, I tried ```this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event?.total);``` but the error is the same and it does not solve the error!!!!

Comment: and also use like this ```this.progress = Math.round(100 * event?.loaded / event?.total);``` but the error is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is returning from `Http` request, so it really can be `undefined`, and in case it will return `undefined` the value that will return to the `progress` variable will `NaN`.
so, you can simply wrap it with condition:

```
if(event?.loaded && event?.total ) {
   this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total)
 }
```

or, give it a default value:

```
 this.progress = Math.round(100 * (event.loaded || 1) / (event.total || 1))
```